# DT_DIR undefined

Tags: c, c99, readdir

I want to check if file returned by `readdir` is directory. 
I tried do it using `DT_DIR` constant (as `man readdir` says) but it's undefined. What file should I include to get it?

Now I use

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
```

gcc version is 4.6.1

Compilation string:

```
gcc a.c --std=c99 -Wall
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to have the `_BSD_SOURCE` feature test macro defined to get those defines, they are not standard, and GCC does not define that macro when compiling for C99.

```
gcc -std=c99 -D_BSD_SOURCE -Wall a.c
```

Comment: Hm, thanks it works. But I guess it isn't always OK. to change this constant, because it may change something else. Is it way to do it other way? Are my own constants OK(i really don't think so) or they may be changed on other OS? (i.e 4 for me with directories)

Comment: PS: `-D_BSD_SOURCE` is enough, we needn't value here

Comment: Using `-D_BSD_SOURCE` doesn't change any constants. It pulls in additional defines and functions that come from BSD and are not POSIX or standard C. If your code requires that, then it is not portable. If you want it to be portable, don't rely on the `d_type` field of `struct dirent`, use `stat` instead. Hardcoding `4` is a bad idea.

Comment: Since version 2.19 of glibc the macro `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` should be used instead of `_BSD_SOURCE`.