# Unknown error using Makefile with augment "-std=c11" or "std=c99"

Tags: c, makefile

I tried to use a Makefile to start my C program, with command lines like
`cc -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -c build.c`. I declared `#include <dirent.h>` in both the header file and the build.c (the one using `<dirent.h>`).

Somehow, it is unable to start with `-std=c11` or `-std=c99`, it will return an error:

> error: ‘DT_DIR’ undeclared (first use in this function)

(both `c11` or `c99`) if I include one of these arguments in my Makefile.

If I remove it, it works perfectly. Since the  `-std=c11 -Wall -Werror` is compulsory, is there any way to solve this?

With reference to [DT_DIR undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241538/dt-dir-undefined), I can't use `-D_BSD_SOURCE` as it is deprecated.

Makefile

```c
PROJECT = test
HEADERS = $(PROJECT).h
OBJECT = build.o

C11     =  cc -std=c11
CFLAGS  =  -Wall -Werror

$(PROJECT):$(OBJECT)
    $(C11) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROJECT) $(OBJECT) -lm
$(OBJECT):%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(C11) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

The content of `build.c` should not affect the result as without the `-std=c11` it still works.

Comment: If you cannot define `_BSD_SOURCE`, then you need to compile with another standard. If you cannot do that either, you are lost.

Comment: If you don't want to define `_BSD_SOURCE` you can define `_GNU_SOURCE` (if you're using GNU libc, for example on a GNU/Linux system).  If you can't define any of these "extra" options and you have to use vanilla POSIX code with no extensions, then you can't use `DT_DIR` because, as the duplicate question shows, that is not part of the POSIX standard.  You'll have to rewrite your code to not use `DT_DIR` (for example, use `stat()` on each file and check that to see if it's a directory).

Comment: [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241538/dt-dir-undefined#comment11641602_9241608) from the linked question gives good advice.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And [edit] your question to show us a [mre] of the actual code.

Comment: And the problem isn't how you build your code (which makes my answer not an answer at all) but that you attempt to use non-standard and non-portable structure-members. If you read [this official POSIX `<dirent.h>` reference](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/dirent.h.html)  you will see that it only specifies two members of the structure. If you read [the Linux `readdir` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) it will have the information you need to use the `d_type` meber and the `DT_DIR` macro (define the `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` macro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it will solve your problem, but I suggest you simplify the `Makefile` some, to rely on [*implicit rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) for the compilation and building of your project.

Only list the flags, options and dependencies in your `Makefile` and let `make` handle the rest:

```
# Flags for the compiler CC when building object files
CFLAGS = -std=c11 -Wall -Werror

# Flags for the linker LD when building the executable program
LDFLAGS = -std=c11

# Libraries for the linker to link with
LBLIBS = -lm

# List dependencies

test: build.o

build.o: build.c test.h
```

This will create the object file `build.o` from the source file `build.c`, with a dependency on the `test.h` header file. Then it will link the `build.o` object file to create the `test` executable program, linking with `-lm`.

Comment: This might be useful cleanup, but this isn't going to solve the question asked.